# Is there a way to add GNOME Night Light to Ubuntu Unity 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, applet

Like the title. If it's possible, how to add GNOME Night Light to a standard Ubuntu Unity 16.04?

Comment: I used redshift, f.lux and others. GNOME Night Light is a part of OS, I mean a night light mode in control panel integrated in system.

Comment: Understood. Just to point out one thing, Night Light is not even available for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (shell version 3.18.x). It was introduced in v3.24, so it's there in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

Comment: I think you should add the part that you're not looking for alternatives like redshift, f.lux etc. to your question.

Comment: But `redshift-gtk` *is* integrated into control panel on Unity.

Comment: @mchid, you could make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used f.lux and redshift. They work great and are easy to use and configure. But it looks like gnome 3.24 has the filter built in, as well as Ubuntu 17.10, which is when Ubuntu switched from Unity back to Gnome.

So to answer your question, no I don't think the gnome night light has been implemented in unity.

https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/
https://www.fosslinux.com/2532/how-to-enable-night-light-mode-in-ubuntu-17-10.htm